# How to copy DataGrid cell value to clipboard

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid`. But I want to get focused cell value in `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event. But `e.ClipboardRowContent` returns me all selected cells values because of the `SelectionUnit`. And i must not change selection unit of datagrid. For solving the problem i need to get focused cell column number. Then I will remove all column values from `clipboarcContent`.
How can i get focused cell in `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Improved version of Farhad's answer

```
private void DataGrid_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    var currentCell = e.ClipboardRowContent[ dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex];
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Clear();
    e.ClipboardRowContent.Add( currentCell );
}
```

Comment: Will this event be triggered automatically on cell click?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following code in order control clipboard content.

```
Clipboard.SetText("some value");
```

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution.
First of all I have needed column number of the focused cell. I have managed to get it with this code:

```
DataGridResults.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
```

Then in `CopyingRowClipboardContent` event, I must delete all other column values.

```
private void DataGridResults_CopyingRowClipboardContent(object sender, DataGridRowClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    int y = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < e.EndColumnDisplayIndex; i++)
    {
        if (i != DataGridResults.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)
        {
            e.ClipboardRowContent.RemoveAt(i - y);
            y++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this solution worked for me on all DataGrids; even ones that had hidden columns.

```
// Clipboard Row content only includes entries for visible cells
// Figure out the actual column we are looking for (taking into account hidden columns)
int columnIndex = dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
var column = dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex];

// Find the associated column we're interested in from the clipboard row content
var cellContent = clipboardRowContent.Where(item => item.Column == column).First();
clipboardRowContent.Clear();
clipboardRowContent.Add(cellContent);
```